# The service configuration is `nil` when instantiating AWSLambdaInvoker on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to implement a lambda function with an iOS app. I follow all the steps on this tutorial form AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/how-to-ios-lambda.html.

But when I add the following line:

```
let lambdaInvoker = AWSLambdaInvoker.default()
```

it throws this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The service configuration is `nil`. You need to configure `Info.plist` or set `defaultServiceConfiguration` before using this method.'
```

---

I added the awsconfiguration.json file to the project with this content:

```
{
"Version": "1.0",
"CredentialsProvider": {
    "CognitoIdentity": {
        "Default": {
            "PoolId": "us-east-1:05aab771-99b5-4a9b-8448-de92fe86ba56",
            "Region": "us-east-1"
        }
    }
},
"IdentityManager" : {
  "Default" : {

  }
}
}
```

The app runs well importing AWSLambda and the mobileClient, and I'm able to validate credentials with Cognito (I get the "welcome to AWS" message)

Any ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to update your `awsconfiguraiton.json` file to have information about `LambdaInvoker` so that it can load the configuration for default service configuration. Your updated file should look like:

```html
{
  "Version": "1.0",
  "CredentialsProvider": {
    "CognitoIdentity": {
        "Default": {
            "PoolId": "us-east-1:05aab771-99b5-4a9b-8448-de92fe86ba56",
            "Region": "us-east-1"
        }
    }
  },
  "IdentityManager" : {
    "Default" : {

    }
  },
  "LambdaInvoker" : {
    "Default" : {
         "Region": "us-east-1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this solved my issue. I thought it was this problem, but couldn't find how to update the json...

Comment: As I mentioned, I solved this issue, but then I run in to another with the credentials! if could take a look I'd be very thankful, I'm not having any answers... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52214407/cognitoidentitycredentials-is-not-authorized-to-perform-lambdainvokefunction-o